# power failure during installation of ubuntu

Tags: installation, power-management

i'm installing ubuntu 13.04 from a pendrive to a windows xp desktop. After starting the installation few minutes later there was a power failure. All i could see now is a ubuntu screen with 5 dots on it. any help please?

Comment: @Danatela Why would the answers there fix the problem of Ubuntu *not being completely installed?* This does not seem like any of the usual situations with a blank screen. (Also, this is not a blank screen...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your GRUB may be crashed or booting files are missing , so repair your boot loader or GRUB from same ( ubuntu 13.04) pen drive.

Comment: how do i do that? Im a rookie. please help.

Comment: plug-in your pen drive , boot ubuntu and there is an option for boot repair. 
visit:-  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair